# Pandas: How to plot multiple dataframes with same index on the same plot using plotly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I have a few dataframes that is each dedicated to 1 single city. **The date column is the index. They all share the same date index.** The only column is the sales of a particular  in that city on that day, with column name being the city name. They look like these:

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | City_A |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| ...        |        |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-30 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-31 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
```

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | City_B |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| ...        |        |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-30 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-31 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
```

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | city_C |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-01-02 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| ...        |        |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-30 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-12-31 | ...    |
+------------+--------+
```

I would like to plot all cities daily sales in 2020 in one single line chart, with x axis being the date, and y axis being the daily sales. Each city has its own line with unique color, **in Plotly**.

Usually if I only have a few cities (for example, 3 cities), I would just merge the 3 dataframes together and plot it. However, the real data I have contains **30+ cities**, so I am wondering if it makes sense at all to merge all those 30+ cities' separate dataframes before plotting it? Is there a quick and elegant way to plot those together without having to merge the 30+ dataframes first?

Much appreciation for your help!

Comment: The real data I have contain 30+ dataframes though. I am wondering if it makes sense to merge all those dataframes together before plotting.

Comment: Do you want one line per city? If so you could make subplots/add taces to a figure with  shared axes and use the separate df's as the data for each line

Comment: ohh....sorry I didn't read your full question

Comment: how do you store the 30+ dataframes, in a list, in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

- 1. generate sample data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import datetime


data1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2021,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(20)],
'city1': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(20))})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2021,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(20)],
'city2': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(20))})


data3 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2021,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(20)],
'city3': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(20))})

dataall = data1.merge(data2).merge(data3)
# dataall = data1.merge(data2, how='left', left_on='date', right_on='date')
dataall
```

show data:
[image]

- 2. use plotly to plot multiple line or bar in one plot

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
for col in ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']:

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = dataall['date'], y = dataall[col], name=col))
fig.show()
```

[image]

`Plotly`'s `graph_objs` method can add a lot of complex graphics to the same graphics, very restful. get more detail, click link: https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

Answer (score 0):

There's a myriad of ways to do this. In your case, the best approach will depend on how you're willing to handle your dataframes. I would strongly consier reshaping them to a long format, and then concatenate them so that you'll end up with *one* dataframe like this:

```
        date city  value
0 2020-01-01    A      1
1 2020-02-01    A      2
2 2020-03-01    A      2
0 2020-01-01    B      3
1 2020-02-01    B      2
2 2020-03-01    B      3
0 2020-01-01    C      2
1 2020-02-01    C      2
2 2020-03-01    C      4
```

Now you can unleash the powers of plotly express and handle the plotting in one line:

```
px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'value', color = 'city')
```

#### Plot 1: Plotly express

[image]

If for some reason you're stuck with using separate dataframes, I would organize them in a dictionary so that you can easily handle them in a `for loop` and use `fig.add_traces(go.Scatter)` like this:

```
dfs = {'A': df1,
       'B': df2,
       'C': df3}

fig = go.Figure()
for df in dfs:
    col = 'City_' + df
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x = dfs[df].date, y = dfs[df][col],
                              mode = 'lines',name = col))
```

#### Plot 2: go.Scatter

The plot is the same with slight differences in the legend and axis notations.

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'city': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'value':[1,2,2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'city': ['B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'value':[3,2,3]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'city': ['C', 'C', 'C'],
                    'value':[2,2,4]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 0)

fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'value', color = 'city')
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'City_A':[1,2,2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'City_B':[3,2,3]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020.01.01', '2020.02.01' , '2020.03.01']),
                    'City_C':[2,2,4]})

dfs = {'A': df1,
       'B': df2,
       'C': df3}

fig = go.Figure()
for df in dfs:
    col = 'City_' + df
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x = dfs[df].date, y = dfs[df][col],
                              mode = 'lines',name = col))
    
fig.show()
```